# Impose a boundary condition to a function

Tags: equation-solving, functions

**Background**

I am trying to impose a boundary condition on a function of two variables $u(x_1,x_2)$. The boundary condition is: $u(x_1,0)=A\cos(\omega x_1)$. The same function in mathematica  $u(x_1,0)$ (before imposing the boundary conditions) is:

```
1. a12x q1x Cos[omega x1] - 1. a12y q1y Cos[omega x1] + 1. a22x q2x Cos[omega x1] - 1. a22y q2y Cos[omega x1] + a32x q3x Cos[omega x1] - a32y q3y Cos[omega x1] + 1. a12y q1x Sin[omega x1] + 1. a12x q1y Sin[omega x1] + 1. a22y q2x Sin[omega x1] + 1. a22x q2y Sin[omega x1] + a32y q3x Sin[omega x1] + a32x q3y Sin[omega x1]
```

As you can see this function contains both sine and cosine components with several constants like a12x, q1x, a12y etc. I want to use the boundary condition to get two constants say q1x and q1y, in terms of other constants (there will be two equations - 1. for setting the sine component to zero and the other for setting the amplitude of the cosine component to A).

**Question**

What is the most elegant way to impose this boundary condition in mathematica? I have tried using:

```
q1sol = FullSimplify[Solve[
  {1.` a12x q1x Cos[omega x1] - 1.` a12y q1y Cos[omega x1] + 
  1.` a22x q2x Cos[omega x1] - 1.` a22y q2y Cos[omega x1] + 
  a32x q3x Cos[omega x1] - a32y q3y Cos[omega x1] == 
 A Cos[omega x1], +1.` a12y q1x Sin[omega x1] + 
  1.` a12x q1y Sin[omega x1] + 1.` a22y q2x Sin[omega x1] + 
  1.` a22x q2y Sin[omega x1] + a32y q3x Sin[omega x1] + 
  a32x q3y Sin[omega x1] == 0}, {q1x, q1y}]]
```

which sets the amplitude of cosine to A and sine to zero. This works but just  equating the whole function with both sine and cosine terms to $A\cos(\omega x_1)$ did not work. (Mathematica probably could not understand that the amplitude of sine should be set to zero)

Comment: What if you use `Chop[]` on your last snippet?

Comment: Chop works but as far as I remember it only changes the display. What if I later need to make a plot, won't it ask for the variables q2x and q2y?

Comment: "works" - then to confirm or disprove your hypothesis of "it only changes the display", have a look at the `InputForm[]` of the result.

Comment: Oh right, Chop does the job. Thanks.